# Moved MSM site to new server now images wont show on frontend

Tags: multi-site-manager

I moved my MSM installation to a new server and now am unable see uploaded images on the front end of either site.

My setup looks like this:

```
└── domain1.com
    ├── admin.php
    ├── index.php
    └── assets
        ├── css
        ├── img
        ├── js
        └── templates
             ├── default
             └── domain2
    ├── images
    ├── system
    ├── themes
    └── domain2.com
        ├── admin.php
        └── index.php
```

If I visit domain1.com or domain2.com front end I can only see background images set through css (contained in '/assets/img' folder.  I cannot see any of the images rendered through EE in the 'images' folder.  Permissions are set to '777' for all image folders.

If I log into the backend I can see the images in file manager and view them as well by clicking on them - images are rendered correctly.  I changed image uploaded preference paths for all folders after moving the site and assume these are correct as I can see the images in the back end as previously mentioned.

I am a bit baffled here.  I have cleared browser and EE cache. Any ideas?

** Edits to included information requested **

.htaccess

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have simply dropped in the .htaccess from the previous domain, but I have noticed that this is not working.  To access deeper pages I am still have to add the "index.php" unfortunately.  This htaccess did work correctly on previous domain.

- Check your upload preferences paths are correct. On the frontend can you target the (uploaded) images directly? Yes, I can navigate directly to an image so I assume the path are correct.
- Can you access domain2.com from the frontend? Yes, and domain2 has the exact same issue as well, backend css images work, images uploaded through CP do not.
- With that folder structure you might have issues with being able to
  access domain2 from domain1. e.g. domain1.com/domain2.com – I may need to clarify: I was using domain1.com and domain2.com for simplicity really I am dealing with a cPanel and an addon domain.  So domain one is in the cPanel account and domain2.com is simple a folder inside that currently.  I am going to add the subdomains dev.domain1.com and dev.domain2.com to these sites as I figured this would allow more direct access for EE and maybe the url structure is confusing EE.

Comment: Check your upload preferences paths are correct.

Could be an .htaccess issue - please provide. On the frontend can you target the (uploaded) images directly?  Can you access domain2.com from the frontend? With that folder structure you might have issues with being able to access domain2 from domain1. e.g. http://domain1.com/domain2.com

Comment: @PeterLewis Thanks for your response, I have made edits to answer your questions.

Comment: Update - this is an imagesizr issue, haven't solved it, but narrowed it down.  I can see and select images in CP for entries, but imagesizr is not displaying anything.  Turned on template debugging and image paths are not being built correctly.  Setting base_path got me closer, but I think setting up the subdomains would solve these issues.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest porting over to CE Image http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-image or ED Imageresizer http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ed-imageresizer as the one I think you're referring to has had development abandoned a few years ago and is buggy.

Comment: It appears after reading devotee that ED Imagesizer will not work with MSM, have you used CE image with MSM  before? Also would you write your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it please.  I appreciated your help and wanted to make sure you got credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Image resizer plugin you're referring to has been abandon, so there has been no support or development for many years. I'd highly recommend using CE Image, I've used this on numerous sites, including MSM and the paths can easily be set via the config file:

http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/configuration#msm_config